# Why is there a visible lag during this CSS transition?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

The transition of this html element  has a visible lag **the first time it runs**. This card flipping mechanism is smooth after you hover over it more than once. Can someone explain why and also how to fix it?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.k-card {
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 250px;
  margin: 2%;
  border-color: white;
  height: 330px;
}

.k-card-image {
  text-align: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.k-card-footer {
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 25px;
}


/* The flip card container - set the width and height to whatever you want. We have added the border property to demonstrate that the flip itself goes out of the box on hover (remove perspective if you don't want the 3D effect */

.flip-card {
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 330px;
}


/* This container is needed to position the front and back side */

.flip-card-inner {
  border-radius: 25px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}


/* Do an horizontal flip when you move the mouse over the flip box container */

.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}


/* Position the front and back side */

.flip-card-front,
.flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* Safari */
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 25px;
}


/* Style the front side */

.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #18988B;
}

.k-button.k-primary {
  background-color: #18988B;
  padding: 2px;
  border-color: #18988B;
}


/* Style the back side */

.flip-card-back {
  background-color: #58595B;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="flip-card k-card">
  <div class="flip-card-inner">
    <div class="flip-card-front">
      <br />
      <center>
        <img class="k-card-image" src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1003/400/400.jpg" width="70%" />
      </center>
      <div class="k-card-footer">
        <p>REPORTS</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back">
      <br />
      <center>
        <img class="k-card-image" src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1001/400/400.jpg" width="70%" />
      </center>
      <div class="k-card-footer">
        <p>TEST</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Also, a link to jsfiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/McRobBlob/s9f07wgy/

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trouble is with property `transform-style: preserve-3d;`.

Remove it from `.flip-card-inner` block and move it to `.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner` block.

```css
.flip-card-inner {
  border-radius: 25px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
/*  transform-style: preserve-3d; remove */
}


/* Do an horizontal flip when you move the mouse over the flip box container */

.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform-style: preserve-3d; /* add */
}
```

**UPDATE**

After @TemaniAfif comment I have better solution:

Just remove `backface-visibility: hidden;` from your css.

```css
.flip-card-front,
.flip-card-back {
/* -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; remove */
/* backface-visibility: hidden;  remove */
}
```

Comment: the animation will be different, it flicker when you mouseout

Comment: removing backface-visibility will also creates issue during the animation since the back will be slightly visible on rotation.

Comment: I think it looks ok.

Comment: maybe not in all the browsers. On my Chrome (Windows) i can see a small *bad* effect.

Answer (score 1):

I would try adding `will-change: transform;` or `will-change: auto;` to `.flip-card-inner`.

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/will-change